# Where does Struts requestprocessor , Action class and Form Bean class fit in MVC?

Tags: struts

This question is regarding struts 1.2. As we know struts follows the mvc archtecture. If we define the mvc classes in struts then jsp is view,controller is actionservlet and model is datastore and classes manipulating the data in datastore like dao class, Businees logic class and value objects. **Right?**

My question is where we can fit requestprocessor class ,action class like baseaction,dispatc action and Form Bean class in mvc. I mean they are considered as part of controller or model?

Second is Which class act as requestdisptcher in struts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the Struts 1.2 documentation:

http://struts.apache.org/1.2.9/userGuide/introduction.html#mvc

http://struts.apache.org/1.2.9/userGuide/building_model.html

The model isn't *just* the datastore, it includes the `ActionForm`, and the mapping between the two.

The `ActionServlet` works *with* the `RequestProcessor` and `ActionMapping`s to implement the controller: the `ActionServlet` delegates action lookup to the `RequestProcessor` so cannot be said to be the controller in itself.

Note that the definitions/differences between the various components may not always map precisely to individual components. Struts 1 provides a somewhat-close mapping between the original ideas of MVC, translated into web applications, and the technologies available at the time.

Comment: The `ActionForm` is an anomaly in the MVC realm. It acts as a transfer object between the controller and the view but more importantly: **It is not part of the Model**.

Comment: It's *Struts'* model, though.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, but it is good practice to limit its use to what it was created for and not pass it along to the Model thus making it (conceptually) part of the Model. It's best to avoiding tight coupling between the Model and the Controller. Just wanted to add that to your answer.

Comment: I'm not implying that the action form should be part of the underlying model representation, just that S1's presentation of the real model to the world usually includes the ActionForm, for better or worse (worse). IMO an S1 app really has two models: the underlying "true" model, and the UI model. Fugly and impure, but hey :)